# Uncrustify to align cascaded "if conditions"

Tags: format, readability, uncrustify, universalindentgui

the combination of UniversalIndentGUI and Uncrustify works for me very fine and saves me lots of time to format the C source codes.
But I have a small extra question and want to know whether someone can help.

Is it possible to correct the combined if conditions from:

```
if ( (a > 0) 
     && (b > 0) 
     && (c > 0))
{
...
}
```

to

```
if (     (a > 0) 
      && (b > 0) 
      && (c > 0)
    )
{
...
}
```

This may help the readability of the codes to some extend if more conditions are embedded together.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a setting for that.  It would be good idea for uncrustify to offer it.

One not too good of a suggestion would be to define a macro or function:

```
#define ___(arg)  arg
```

and then you could have:

```
if ( ___( a > 0 )
     && ( b > 0 )
   )
{
}
```

but be aware the standard reserves macros that start with '_'. See:

[What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)